# SlickGrid and browser find behavior?

Tags: javascript, scroll, find, slickgrid

Is SlickGrid capable (somehow) of supporting a browser's find capabilities in full? For example, if a user loads 100,000 rows of data, then presses Ctrl+F, can they find results that are outside the viewable area?

From playing around with the SlickGrid samples, it seems to me that SlickGrid doesn't support this out of the box. Try searching for "Task 491" (one of the last rows) after loading this page:
http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html

The mechanisms behind this limitation are easy enough to understand, but I've been unable to find a workaround for it. Should I consider it a lost cause?

Comment: Slickgrid dynamically manipulates the viewable data, as such attempting to search the entire backing-data using the browser-search will not work. Generally, you'll provide [column-filtering](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-header-row.html) in the header row for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, a lost cause. Column-filtering is a decent compromise.

An untested and unproven workaround I'd was to forcibly add the relevant text into obscured divs inside SlickGrid's scrollable panel.

Answer (score 0):

On one of my projects, I actually reassigned Ctrl-F combonation to focus an input inside the web page, so SlickGrid could use it as a source for filter, that you have to write yourself